# Select-option to look nice, in a text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

How do I make a select-option look nice and on "the same line" when it appears in a text?

```
<p class="ptest">This is a
  <select class="selectpicker" data-width="100px">
    <option value="">very good</option>
    <option value="">very bad</option>
  </select> &nbsp;test.
</p>
```

I use Bootstrap and the selectpicker js.

http://jsfiddle.net/18uLb3cd/

Answer (score 0):

There's bottom margin on ".bootstrap-select.btn-group, .bootstrap-select.btn-group[class*="span"]"

To vertically center change

```
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

to

```
margin-bottom: 0;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/18uLb3cd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clearer on what do you mean by "look nice". If you want to understand how to change the default styles of a select box, [here](https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/) is a link to a good article to help you.

Hope it helps!